# Block diagram of 16:1 MUX using four 4:1 MUX only

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer

As far as I know we can make a 16:1 MUX using five 4:1 MUX. For four 4:1 MUX, I think we have to apply NOT to different selection lines but I am not getting the correct configuration to do that.

Comment: The question is not clear. Also, if you provide a schematic or drawings to your question it will improve your explanation a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could've easily found it on the internet if you searched.

**The basis:** See it this way: You need a combinational logic with 16 input pins, 4 select lines and one output. In a 4:1 mux, you have 4 input pins, two select lines and one output.

So, at the least you have to use 4 4:1 MUX, to obtain 16 input lines. But you'd then have a logic with 4 output pins. We can use another 4:1 MUX, to multiplex only one of those 4 outputs at a time. Hence, this would be your final design. There might be other designs methods too, but this is the most common.

[image]

Image courtesy: www.slideplayer.com

**EDIT:**
Yes, we can implement it without using the last 4:1 MUX; but you have to use an OR gate there and also include *enable* pins for each 4:1 MUX. It utilizes the traditional method; drawing a truth table and then analytically deciding the design. Here is an example of an 8:1 MUX from 2:1 MUX without using a 2:1 MUX at the output.

[image]

Image courtesy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=neXhD9qyQmo

But, to obtain the same for a 16:1 MUX you'll need to make a lot of modifications. Like if you draw the truth table and analyze (compare it with the above 8:1 MUX design), you'll require two enable pins for each MUX, each with different options. For example, the first MUX needs to be *enabled* only when the two enable pins(say, e1, e0) are low, the second MUS should be *enabled* only when e1= 0 and e0=1 and so on.

As the size of the MUX increases, it'll become too complex to design using this model. Hence, the first approach is utilized; the one with a MUX at the end. There may be other designs, but this is my approach.

Comment: This thing i know. I am asking is it possible to make a 16:1 MUX without using that last single 4:1 MUX ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Check the edited answer.

Comment: Actually I watched that video before I asked the question here. Anyway thank you for the explanation part. I think I get it now.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

Q 16×1 mux by using 4×1mux 
Ans:.  It contains four 4×1mux are used & it is a 16×1 mux 
16 i/p are used  the selective lines are S0, s1 ,s2, s3 , and 
4 not gates are used and o/p are "y".

See the given image to  verify the logical circuit

```
               It is designed by "Krishna .ch"
```